# Getting Text using Inline Variable Substitution in ArcGIS Desktop ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I am trying to use inline variable substitution (%Input Feature%) to use the name of an output of a Clip Tool (let's call it "(Final) Output Feature Class) as the name of the output table in the next part of the data model (let's call it "Output Table Name").

I have a workspace defined, and when I call the output of (Final) Output Feature Class using inline variable substitution, it tries to use the entire string as the input name - workspace path and all.

Is there a way to call just the last bit of the string for the table name so I am not using the whole path?

Also - I cannot bring it into Python. I am making ArcGIS specific data models for other users.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Parse Path](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/parse-path.htm):

> The Parse Path tool parses the input into its file, path, name, or
>   extension. The output can be used as in-line variables in the output
>   name of other tools.

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for! Thanks!
Using "File" for the value I can then link it to the Table to Table tool as the Output Table for its name.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I found was to create a String variable (let's call it String) using Create Variable within Model Builder's tools. I added this as a precondition to the Clip Tool and as a model parameter to define when I fill out the parameters in the tool.

Then the output feature class of the Clip Tool is set to %Workspace%\%String%, because this parameter is not a model parameter. The Workspace variable, however, is, and becomes defined when the tools parameters are filled out.

Then for the Table Name parameter I use inline variable substitution again with 
%String% to call String's value to also be used as the Table Name parameter.

This way only sounds slightly more complicated and requires a little more work than the Parse Path tool, but in practice it isn't so bad. Both seem to run about the same.